# chown Error trying to install rbenv in Mavericks, using Ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, terminal, osx-mavericks, rbenv

Trying to install rbenv.

### **1. Checked to See brew update**

Started with:

```
$ brew update
```

then got:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

So then I did:

```
$ git init brew update
```

and got:

> usage: git init [-q | --quiet] [--bare] [--template=] [--shared[=]] [directory]

which i assume means it worked.

## **2. Tried Installing rbenv**

Next I did:

```
 $ brew install rbenv
```

And got this:

> ==> Downloading https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/archive/v0.4.0.tar.gz
>
> ################################################################## 100.0%
>
> ==> Caveats
>   To use Homebrew's directories rather than ~/.rbenv add to your profile:
>     export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/var/rbenv
>
> To enable shims and autocompletion add to your profile:
>     if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
>   Warning: Could not link rbenv. Unlinking...
>   Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
>   The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
>   You can try again using `brew link rbenv'
>
> Possible conflicting files are:
>   ==> Summary
>     /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0: 31 files, 152K, built in 2 seconds

### **3. So I tried to Link rbenv**

Tried to link rbenv:

```
$ brew link rbenv
```

And got this message:

> Linking /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0... Warning: Could not link rbenv. Unlinking...
>
> Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0
>   /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs is not writable. You should change its permissions.

### **4. Finally, tried to change ownership**

Finally I tried to chown to change permission:

```
$ chown -R s****i /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs
```

And got these messages:

> chown: /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/apple-gcc42: Operation not permitted
>   chown: /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/autoconf: Operation not permitted
>   chown: /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/automake: Operation not permitted
>   chown: /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/git: Operation not permitted
>   chown: /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/libgpg-error: Operation not permitted
>   chown: /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/libksba: Operation not permitted
>   chown: /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/libtool: Operation not permitted
>   chown: /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/libyaml: Operation not permitted
>   chown: /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/pkg-config: Operation not permitted
>   chown: /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs: Operation not permitted

### **Question**

I'm (clearly) very new to Terminal, and setting up Ruby.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here and how to fix it?

By way of background, I imploded rvm as per the instructions I'm following, and now trying to install rbenv.  Not even sure why, but it seems to be the *au courant* thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to force the ownership change on `/usr/local/` but take note of the current owner (`ls -l /usr/local`) in the case of problems: and try `chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local` (append with `sudo`) to elevate the command as an admin if this doesn't work [nb. `-R` will run the ownership change recursively]. Then try `brew link rbenv` again.